# Networking - What is North-South & West-East traffic?

Tags: networking

In most of the solution documents uses the network term -

> North-South & West-East traffic

what do really mean?

Comment: 'Most of the solution documents' such as what? Off topic.

Comment: See [this answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/18873/8499).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/18873/8499,

"east-west" traffic refers to traffic within a data center -- i.e. server to server traffic.

"North-south" traffic is client to server traffic, between the data center and the rest of the network.